# Videlalvaro RabbitMQBundle authentication issue

Tags: symfony, rabbitmq

Currently I am trying to connect to rabbitmq but I am getting the following error. exception 'PhpAmqpLib\Exception\AMQPProtocolConnectionException' with message 'ACCESS_REFUSED - Login was refused using authentication mechanism AMQPLAIN. For details see the broker logfile.

I've been working on it for a few hours now and have no idea on how to fix this. The credentials used by the rabbitmqbundle are also being used by other applications (python/pika), and these have no issue connecting to rabbitmq. The broker log file does not mention any failed authentication attempts either. Also the configuration being used works fine on staging / production environment which are all provisioned automatically.

If anyone has any idea as to what might be causing the issue I would be very happy to hear it. Any ideas on how to further approach this issue are also more than welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may have permissions issues that need to be resolved for that username and password. In the past, I have seen usernames authenticate just fine when logging in to produce / consume message, but fail when logging into the administrative web application, for example. This happened because permissions prevented the user from using the admin app.

Check your username permissions against the required permissions for what you are doing.

Comment: The user has full permissions (configure_priv=*, write_priv=* and read_priv=*), so I don't think that is the issue. There is also no problem for the user to log into the admin panel, or to connect with this account from a different application.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be an issue with aws security groups. 
The error message from AMQPLib is slightly misleading. It should probably be a timeout instead of an Access refused.